# When using nested enumerates, how do I have longer labels start at the same place, after the label of the first environment?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, nesting

I would like to be able to use long labels in a nested `enumerate` environments without having them overlap with the previous level. I don't really know how to properly explain this, so here is a MWE illustrating what I would like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Hello
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Here is a normal enunerate with short labels.
\item
It looks pretty.
\item
I would like to have all of my labels ``start'' at the same place.
\item
That is to say, after the first label.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Stuff
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
Here is an enumerate with long lables.
\item
Notice that the labels start before the label of the containing enumerate environment.
\item
I find this undesirable.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
As you can see, the issue becomes even more obvious when there is no content after the first label, so the labels actually overlap.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: On a side note, how to I show what the code outputs, in addition to just the code itself, so people can quickly see what I would like?

Comment: You can take a screen shot of your pdf and upload it.

Comment: Oh is that really it? I thought there was some more fancy means lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### With `enumerate`

You said in your previous question that you would have preferred not to switch to `enumitem` but to stay with `enumerate` package.

Using the latter and adding

```
\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}
```

to the preamble (as I said in your previous question) solves the issue.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Hello
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Here is a normal enunerate with short labels.
\item
It looks pretty.
\item
I would like to have all of my labels ``start'' at the same place.
\item
That is to say, after the first label.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Stuff
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
Here is an enumerate with long lables.
\item
Notice that the labels start before the label of the containing enumerate environment.
\item
I find this undesirable.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
As you can see, the issue becomes even more obvious when there is no content after the first label, so the labels actually overlap.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### With `enumitem`

Instead, if you have already switched to `enumitem`, you can solve your issue by adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{
  leftmargin=*
}
```

so that your modified MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{
  leftmargin=*
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Hello
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Here is a normal enunerate with short labels.
\item
It looks pretty.
\item
I would like to have all of my labels ``start'' at the same place.
\item
That is to say, after the first label.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Stuff
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
Here is an enumerate with long lables.
\item
Notice that the labels start before the label of the containing enumerate environment.
\item
I find this undesirable.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
As you can see, the issue becomes even more obvious when there is no content after the first label, so the labels actually overlap.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is accidental usage and and hoc changes are remaining:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newlength{\LLwidth}
\settowidth{\LLwidth}{Long Label a)}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Hello
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Here is a normal enunerate with short labels.
\item
It looks pretty.
\item
I would like to have all of my labels ``start'' at the same place.
\item
That is to say, after the first label.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}
\item
Stuff
\leftmarginii\LLwidth
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
Here is an enumerate with long lables.
\item
Notice that the labels start before the label of the containing enumerate environment.
\item
I find this undesirable.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\leftmarginii\LLwidth
\begin{enumerate}[{Long Label} a)]
\item
As you can see, the issue becomes even more obvious when there is no content after the first label, so the labels actually overlap.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the length '\LLwidth'? And looking at the nestings, it still looks like the long labels are shifted far more to the left than the standard labels are :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if it is simply that nested enumerated environments are always 'smaller' than their parents, this does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}% <-- just to give some perspective
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlist{labelindent=0pt, align=left}

\newlength\LLwidth
\settowidth{\LLwidth}{Long Label a}% <-- this is not good for consistency
\setlength{\LLwidth}{3cm}%           <-- this is better; but maybe pick a font-based value

\begin{document}

\noindent lksjdf

\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Here is a normal enunerate with short labels.
  \item It looks pretty.
  \item I would like to have all of my labels ``start'' at the same
    place.
  \item That is to say, after the first label.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}
\item Stuff

  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelwidth={\LLwidth}, label={Long Label
      \alph*)}]

  \item Here is an enumerate with long lables.

  \item Notice that the labels start before the label of the containing
    enumerate environment.

  \setcounter{enumii}{12}%  <-- just to see a wider label in effect
  \item I find this undesirable.

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item ~ % <-- prevent the overlap

  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelwidth={\LLwidth}, label={Long Label
      \alph*)}]

  \item As you can see, the issue becomes even more obvious when there
    is no content after the first label, so the labels actually overlap.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you are doing a bunch of weird things with long labels, I recommend you use the `\setlist` capabilities of `enumitem` to maintain consistency across list environments.